# What exactly web3.eth.accounts.create do

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, accounts

When `web3.eth.accounts.create` is used to create an account something like this can be seen.

```
web3.eth.accounts.create();
> {
    address: "0xb8CE9ab6943e0eCED004cDe8e3bBed6568B2Fa01",
    privateKey: "0x348ce564d427a3311b6536bbcff9390d69395b06ed6c486954e971d960fe8709",
    signTransaction: function(tx){...},
    sign: function(data){...},
    encrypt: function(password){...}
}
```

now if `web3.eth.accounts.encrypt(privateKey, password);` is executed using the same privatekey that we got from the previous step we can get a output as the web3 keystore v3 standard. Now if we store this file in the geth node's keystore folder (ex `user/.ethereum/private/keystore`) and run `personal.listAccounts` we can get our created address on that list.

So when I need to unlock this account with `web3.personal.unlockAccount` what would be the passphrase that I need to give to unlock my account?

Answer (score 3):

`web3.eth.accounts.create();` already creates a new account

You can look the new account info using something like this in js:

`var account = web3.eth.accounts.create();   //Creates the account (is an object)
console.log(account);   //show the object in the console`

Then, if you want to get the keystore you have to provide the privateKey and a password using something like this:

`var walletprivate = account["privateKey"];   //Get the private key from the object
var phppasswallet = "THE_PASSWORD";   //provide a password
var keystore = web3.eth.accounts.encrypt(walletprivate, phppasswallet);   //Get the keystore`

But this is just if you want the keystore for the account; with the `web3.eth.accounts.create();` the account is already created and you can use it directly with the private key

Answer (score 1):

It's the `password` used in the `encrypt` function.

What you do here is, store the private key of your account encrypted(so no one can find it by just accessing the keystore files) using the password.

In order to unlock the account you need to get the private key bck by decrypting it. There you need to provide the password used for encryption.

Comment: `personal.unlockAccount` only accepts address and passphrase so how can I unlock that created account which was encrypted by my encryption passphrase.

Comment: does web3.eth.accounts.create() actually create a new account? If it use it with testrpc I can't see a new account.

Comment: I'm getting web3.eth.accounts.create is not a function. How do you resolve this?

Comment: web3.eth.accounts.create() was introduced in web3 1.0. you should be using a earlier version. check your web3 version